# Google Cloud Storage - Can't add bucket with domain, ownership error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a bucket as sub.domain.com but I am getting the error "The bucket you tried to create is a domain name owned by another user."

I have verified the ownership in Webmaster Tools and even un-verified and re-verified. I'm logged into the account that has both Webmaster Tools and the Cloud Storage account.

I have other buckets with the same structure for other domains that I've verified with Webmaster Tools but this is the only one that is giving me that error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this without paying $150 to open a ticket with Google?

Comment: One common mistake that might cause this is to verify something like "www.domain.com" instead of "domain.com". Subdomain.domain.com is not a subdomain of www.domain.com, and so it wouldn't work.

Comment: I checked just to make sure but it was just "domain.com" that I verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain had been verified by another email previously years ago but the domain was not listed logging into that account. The other email was not listed as a domain owner either.

The way I fixed it was to re-add the domain using that old email, it didn't require verification stating that it was verified with a TXT record already. I then added the email address that has the Cloud Storage as an owner and can now see both owners when logged in.

Once that was done I was able to create the bucket. It seems that I had just run into a weird edge case.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your follow-up noting that the domain was previously verified using a different email address, I think what probably happened was:

- The domain ownership registration system periodically re-verifies each registration (e.g., retrieving the DNS TXT record for that domain, the meta tag from the site's home page, etc.)
- You updated the registration and then tried to create the bucket before that re-verification scan ran, so it still found the old record.
- Since that the verification scan ran, so found your new registration.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

If you tell us the specific bucket name/domain name you're trying to use, we can investigate. If you'd rather not post the name on StackOverflow you can send it to us privately, at gs-team@google.com.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario which can easily be overlooked is: if you are working with the command line tools (e.g. gsutil mb gs://some.domain), then you are likely working from a service account. In the webmaster central you can add the service account email to the list of owners for an already verified domain (by another account).